# Functions in C language that manipulate strings, not present in the standard C library

Tags: c, strings

I have implemented few functions in C language that manipulate strings. These functions are not present in the standard C library.

---

### string_library.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "string_library.h"


/*
 * get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters(char *str, long size):
 *
 * Function get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters() reads at most
 * 'size - 1' characters into 'str' from stdin and then appends the NULL
 * character ('\0'). In all cases, reading input stops after encountering a
 * newline ('\n') or EOF even if 'size - 1' characters have not been read.
 * If a newline ('\n') or EOF is read then these are replaced by NULL character
 * ('\0'). If there are extra characters in input, they are read and discarded.
 * In all cases, str is returned.
 *
 */
char *get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters(char *str, long size)
{

    char c = 0;
    long num_chars_to_read = size - 1;
    long i = 0;

    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    if (num_chars_to_read <= 0)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < num_chars_to_read; i++) {

        c = getchar();

        if ((c == '\n') || (c == EOF)) {
            str[i] = 0;
            return str;
        }

        str[i] = c;

    } // end of for loop

    str[i] = 0;

    // discard rest of input
    while ((c = getchar()) && (c != '\n') && (c != EOF));

    return str;

} // end of get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters


int is_string_empty(const char *str)
{

    if (!str)
        return 1;

    if (*str == 0)
        return 1;

    return 0;

} // end of is_string_empty


int is_string_all_whitespace(const char *str)
{

    char *temp = (char *)(str);

    if (is_string_empty(str))
        return 1;

    while (*temp) {
        if ((*temp != ' ') && (*temp != '\t'))
            return 0;
        temp++;
    }

    return 1;

} // is_string_all_whitespace


/*
 * This function fills 'str' with 'len - 1' random characters and appends a null
 * byte at the end and returns 'str'.
 */
char *get_random_string(char *str, long len)
{

    int min_num = 32;
    int max_num = 126;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < (len - 1); i++) {
        str[i] = (random() % (max_num - min_num + 1)) + min_num;
    }

    str[len - 1] = 0;

    return str;

}


/*
 * str_replace_chr(char *str, const char orig, const char new):
 *
 * Function str_replace_chr() replaces all occurrences of 'orig' character in
 * the string 'str' with the 'new' character. If 'str' is NULL then nothing is
 * done. In all cases, 'str' is returned.
 *
 */
char *str_replace_chr(char *str, const char orig, const char new)
{

    char *orig_str = (str);

    if (!str)
        return orig_str;

    while (*str) {
        if (*str == orig)
            *str = new;
        str++;
    }

    return orig_str;

} // end of str_replace_chr


/*
 * substr(const char *str, long start_index, long end_index):
 *
 * Function substr() allocates memory and returns a pointer to a string / character
 * array which is a substring of 'str' starting from index 'start_index' till
 * 'end_index' (inclusive). This substring is terminated by NULL byte at the end.
 * If 'str' is NULL or 'start_index' is less than 0 or 'end_index' is less than 0
 * or 'end_index' is less than 'start_index' then NULL is returned.
 *
 * The returned pointer points to a memory region containing the substring and this
 * memory region was allocated using malloc. So, it is the user's responsibility to
 * free the allocated memory.
 *
 */
char *substr(const char *str, long start_index, long end_index)
{

    char *substring = NULL;
    long length = 0;
    long i = 0;

    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    if ((start_index < 0) || (end_index < 0) || (end_index < start_index))
        return NULL;

    length = end_index - start_index + 1;

    substring = malloc(length + 1); // extra 1 byte for NULL byte
    if (!substring)
        return NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        substring[i] = str[i + start_index];
    }

    substring[i] = 0;

    return substring;

} // end of substr
```

Comment: Would you show us the header too?  I doubt it contains anything too controversial, but it's always helps, for a full review.

Answer (score 9):

### `get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters`

> ```
>     c = getchar();
> ```

`c` is a `char`, so we lose the ability to distinguish `EOF` here.  We need to use `int` for that.

The whole function could be made much simpler: just use `fgets()`, then if the final character read was `\n`, overwrite it, else discard the rest of the line with `scanf("%*[^\n]"),scanf("%*c")`.

### `is_string_empty`

The name is very close to those reserved for standard library extension, but is legal because `is` is followed by underscore rather than a lower-case letter.

It would be better named as `is_string_null_or_empty`, as a null pointer is quite different from an empty string.  It could be simplified, too:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_string_empty(const char *str)
{
    return !str || !*str;
}
```

### `is_string_all_whitespace`

Don't cast away `const` like that.  `temp` can be a pointer to `const char`.

I'm surprised that only space and tab are considered - why not everything that's `isspace()`?

This too could be much simpler:

```
#include <ctype.h>

bool is_string_null_or_all_whitespace(const char *s)
{
    if (!s) { return true; }
    for (;;) {
        if (!*s) { return true; }
        if (!isspace((unsigned char)(*s++))) { return false; }
    }
}
```

### `get_random_string`

Is there any value in returning the pointer that was passed?  Consider a return type of `void` instead.

The length should probably be a `size_t` rather than `long`.

Those min and max values suggest that you're assuming the target is using ASCII - if so, that assumption should be documented (and preferably tested so that where it's untrue, users get a compilation error rather than random behaviour).

Is there a good reason not to use the standard library `rand()` for this function?

```
#include <assert.h>

void get_random_string(char *str, size_t len)
{
    assert(' ' == 32);          /* This function assumes ASCII */
    static const char min_num = 32;
    static const char max_num = 126;

    while (len--) {
        *str++ = (char)(rand() % (max_num - min_num + 1) + min_num);
    }
    *str = '\0';
}
```

### `substr`

If we passed the indices as `size_t`, we wouldn't need to check for negative values.

In modern C, we don't need to declare all our variables at beginning of scope.  It's better to wait until we can initialise them.

We should use the standard `memcpy()` function to copy the contents.  Good compilers will recognise the loop and replace with `memcpy()`, but it's easier to use the function than to write the loop correctly.

We'll get undefined behaviour if we attempt to copy off the end of the array.  We could use `strncpy()` to finish when we reach a null character, or we could measure the length and check that at the start of the function.

I like the good handling for when `malloc()` returns a null pointer.

```
#include <string.h>

char *substr(const char *str, size_t start_index, size_t end_index)
{
    if (!str || !*str ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    const char *end = memchr(str, '\0', end_index);
    if (end) {
        end_index = end - str - 1;
    }
    if (end_index < start_index) {
        return NULL;
    }

    const size_t length = end_index - start_index + 1;

    char *const substring = malloc(length + 1); // include terminating null char
    if (substring) {
        memcpy(substring, str + start_index, length);
        substring[length] = '\0';
    }

    return substring;
}
```

### Overall

I'm disappointed to see no unit tests of these functions.  Including tests in the review helps us understand what's known to work, and often tells us about the anticipated use cases.  I encourage you to include tests whenever possible!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131920/discussion-on-answer-by-toby-speight-functions-in-c-language-that-manipulate-str).

Comment: Toby, I have made following changes in my code according to your review:

(1) I changed c from char to int.
(2) I have done the simplification - I have now used `return ((!str) || (!(*str)));`.
(3) I have changed my code and now I am using isspace().
(4) I have put in documentation that the target is ASCII.
(5) I am planning to use C string library functions from now on (like memcpy(), strncpy(), etc.).

Comment: Toby, `scanf("%*[^\n]"),scanf("%*c")`: Will this work correctly if EOF is encountered without newline being encountered?

Comment: Toby, `long vs size_t`: long is my personal preference. long guards against negative numbers being passed by user by mistake and long is also very large to satisfy almost all user needs. I haven't seen any use case of an integer greater than LONG_MAX (9,223,372,036,854,775,807) when dealing with strings. Also, if the standard C library uses size_t, it doesn't mean that I should also use size_t.

Comment: Toby, `Is there a good reason not to use the standard library rand() for this function?`: The man pages say that random() is better. See the paragraph below NOTES section in this link: https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand.

Comment: Toby, `Good handling of malloc`: I actually handle that situation first where code is less before returning so that it is more clear / more readable to the user. So, sometimes I use `if (!substring)` first and sometimes I use `if (substring)` first.

Comment: Toby, `Is there any value in returning the pointer that was passed?`: There are already few standard C library functions that return the pointer - like, strcat(), strcpy(), etc.

Answer (score 3):

## substr

This function does not work as I expected it to. If I called it like in the following:

```
substr("abc", 1, 1);
```

I would have expected it to return an empty string `""` and not `"b"`.

You should try to limit your function to do a single task. `substr` allocates a new string and writes to it. You can leave the allocation up to the caller.

Suggested replacement:

```
int substr(char* dst, size_t size, const char* src, size_t start, size_t length)
{
    if (length >= size || start + length > strlen(src))
        return -1;
    memmove(dst, src + start, length);
    dst[length] = 0;
    return length;
}
```

This has two advantages over your implementation:

1. You do not have to remember to `free` the results
2. It can be used on pre-existing buffers.

Consider the following

```
struct ipaddress
{
    char part1[4];
    char part2[4];
    char part3[4];
    char part4[4];
};

int main()
{
    char* test = "196.168.332.556";
    struct ipaddress adr;
    substr(adr.part1, 4, test, 0, 3);
    substr(adr.part2, 4, test, 4, 3);
    substr(adr.part3, 4, test, 8, 3);
    substr(adr.part4, 4, test, 12, 3);
}
```

If you used your implementation, you would have had to do an extra `strcpy` and remembered to free the string.

You will also be able to use the same buffer for the source and destination like so:

```
int main()
{
    char test[] = "123ABCDEF456"; 
    substr(test, sizeof(test), test, 3, 6);
    printf("%s\n", test);
}
```

## str_replace_chr

Here you could have used `strchr` to search for the occurrences of `orig`:

```
void str_replace_chr(char* str, const char orig, const char new)
{
    while (str = strchr(str, orig))
    {
        *str++ = new;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider introducing the `restrict` keyword for the pointer arguments to your version of `substr`, to tell the compiler (and the user) that the destination won't overlap the source string?  Was omitting them (and using `memmove()` rather than `memcpy()`) an intentional choice?  Worth elaborating on in your answer...

Comment: @TobySpeight, I considered that it might be legal for the destination to overlap and that is why I used `memmove` instead of `memcpy`. Consider the following `char test[] = "ABCD123"; substr(test, sizeof(test), test, 2, 4);`

Comment: Yep, makes sense.  That looks like a reasonable use-case.

Comment: @TobySpeight, updated. To you think there is any advantage to use `strchr` over manually looping?

Comment: Probably not, but I think it has educational value that makes that section worthwhile.  It shows a different way to look at the problem, and I always find that useful in a review.

Comment: Actually, `strchr()` can be implemented more efficiently than the plain loop on many architectures, so it might have a small performance advantage, particularly when the string is long with few or no matches.

Comment: Maybe be explicit that closed-range indices are rare for good reason, and also say why you prefer and changed to index+length at least for this name.

Comment: @Deduplicator, thanks, I'll do so.

Comment: @jdt, In your code - "substr("abc", 1, 1);" the function works the way I intended it too. May be your expectations were different. From my point of view, if the start_index and end_index are same, then it means that the user wants only 1 character which is at start_index. Also, I didn't leave the responsibility of allocation of memory to the caller because I wanted to make it easier for the caller. I wanted the caller to do as less work as possible.

Comment: I have not called any other C library function from my program because I wanted to save the time cost of calling a function - time taken in setting up stack, etc.

Comment: @Amit, if you're concerned about performance, you really ought to be measuring rather than just guessing.  Even experts find their intuition about performance is often out of line with reality.  I'll be surprised if you can measure the overhead of calling a library function (especially as this will likely be inlined by any decent optimiser).  But I won't say it's definitely not worth it until I see measurements!

Comment: FWIW, the start/end index interface is used by [GNU Make's `$(wordlist)` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-selecting-word-lists), and you're expected to pass (1, 0) to get the empty string.  So there is _some_ precedent, albeit in an unrelated language.

Comment: @Amit re: `substr` I’m not saying that there is anything wrong with the way you are handling the indices but, for me at least, it is not intuitive. If you wanted the function to dynamically allocate memory you can also consider using `strndup`. For usage on pre-existing buffers, you could have considered `strncpy` or using `memmove` and setting the zero-termination character if there is a possibility that the source and destination may overlap. There are many ways to skin a cat as the saying goes :-)

Comment: @Amit re: `str_replace_chr` As Toby has already mentioned, it would be a good exercise to do some benchmarking to see which way is faster. I would guess that you may get slightly better results for small strings with lots of `orig` characters with a manual loop and a slight improvement for a large string with sparse occurrence of `orig` using `strchr`. This may be an interesting follow-up question.

Comment: A few more tests in `substr()` would cope with pathological inputs where `start + length` overflows and `length > INT_MIN`, etc.

Comment: @jdt, I am planning to use C library functions from now on (like memcpy(), strncpy(), strchr(), etc.).

Comment: @jdt, `about using strchr() in function str_replace_chr()`: Using strchr() will result in many function calls of strchr() if there are lots of 'orig' characters in the string. So, using the loop in the function is simple and more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

**Functional difference from `fgets()`**

I'd expect `get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters()` to perform like `fgets()` when there is no input.  Instead `get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters(str, ...)` returns `str`.  `fgets(str, ...)` returns `NULL`.

**Types**

Size of buffer and array indexing is more idiomatic C as `size_t` than `long`.  Even `int` has some precedent, but not `long`.

Use `int c` to save result from `fgetc()` to well distinguish the 257 different responses.  Avoid infinite loops when `char` is *unsigned* and `fgetc()` returns `EOF`.

**Pedantic: signed math overflow**

Perform `if (num_chars_to_read <= 0)` before `long num_chars_to_read = size - 1;` to avoid signed math overflow.

**Missing string_library.h**

**Documentation**

External functions deserve documentation in the .h file.  Consider the user may not have access to the .c file (nor want it).  Documentation in the .c file explains implementation.  Overall functionality, higher level, is for the .h.

**Name space**

`string_library.c` contains various functions that have no or little *name* connection to `string_library.*`.  Consider a more uniform naming convention.

`get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters()` is too long.

**Pedantic: range**

`get_random_string(str,len)` is UB when `len <= 0`.

**[WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET) `()`**

`()` not needed in `char *orig_str = (str);`.

**`NULL` is for pointers**

Rather then comment

```
// extra 1 byte for NULL byte
// use 
extra 1 byte for null character
// or
extra 1 byte for \0
// or
extra 1 byte for nul
```

`NULL` is the *null pointer constant*.  It may be a pointer type.

*null character* is what the C spec uses.

`'\0'` is another good choice

*nul* is defined outside C in ASCII.

**Well uniformly formatted**

**No noticed spelling/grammar issues**

Comment: Chux, - """"get_random_string(str,len) is UB when len <= 0."""" - this is not unbounded because in the for loop, the condition 0 < some_negative_number will not be satisfied and the loop will exit. However, it will crash because of """"str[len - 1] = 0;"""". So, I will fix the code to check 'len' for negative values.

Comment: Chux, """"Perform if (num_chars_to_read <= 0) before long num_chars_to_read = size - 1; to avoid signed math overflow."""" - I don't see how will there be an overflow. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Chux, , I have intentionally avoided size_t because it is unsigned. If by mistake user passes -1 then size_t will lead to a crash because -1 is ULONG_MAX and so str[ULONG_MAX] will crash. Also, malloc() will return NULL because it won't get memory of size ULONG_MAX.

Comment: @Amit "fgets() never returns NULL." C spec has "If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, the contents of the array remain unchanged and _a null pointer is returned_. If a read error occurs during the operation, the array contents are indeterminate and _a null pointer is returned_.  Unclear what code you used that had "If the first character read is '\n' or EOF then ... fgets() will return an empty string".  For some clarity, we are talking about the _return_ value which is either a _null pointer_ or a pointer to a string.

Comment: @Amit "These functions will return only when user presses enter or an EOF is read" not quite.  Other cases: file input buffer full, input error occurs.

Comment: @Amit "how will there be an overflow." --> Pathological case: `get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters(str, LONG_MIN)`

Comment: @Amit "avoided size_t because it is unsigned. If by mistake user passes  ...." --> If the user makes a mistake, then all sorts of unavoidable problems occur.   Using a signed type may give warnings when an proper `size_t` variable is passed as the _size_.    `size_t` is the right size type to use for _all_ object sizing and array indexing - neither too narrow nor too wide.  This tends to be a holy war, so in the end, follow your group's coding standards.  C lib tends to use `size_t`.

Comment: Chux, on all conditions that fgets() returns NULL, my function returns an empty string (the first character of str is made 0). But I will change my code to return NULL as fgets() does.

Comment: @Amit Yes, "the first character of str is made 0", when able, is a good thing on end-of-file and input error.  Even though it is not _needed_ when function returns `NULL` as calling code can switch on that and ignore the buffer, I do not like `fgets()` leaving the buffer unchanged on `NULL` return. I would prefer such input functions to do as your code does: always affect the buffer, even when returning `NULL`.

Comment: Chux, `Use int c to save result from fgetc() to well distinguish the 257 different responses`: I have changed my code and made 'c' an int from char.

Comment: Chux, `Perform if (num_chars_to_read <= 0) before long num_chars_to_read = size - 1; to avoid signed math overflow.`: I have changed the code and actually removed num_chars_to_read variable.

Comment: Chux, `NULL is for pointers`: I have fixed the comment.

Comment: Chux, `size_t vs long`: I gave my comments about this in the comments of strcat_new() review.

Comment: Chux, `get_input_from_stdin_and_discard_extra_characters() is too long.`: But this long name explains clearly what the function is doing. Do you have some name in mind?